# Loop in php script from cron?

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, cron

I have a wordpress php script running as a cron job. it's currently running once a minute per domain indefinitely.

```
    /usr/bin/php -q /home/domain1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tdw/postit.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The problem is my server is getting big with 50+ domains and the crons are running into each other causing errors or crashing the database.

is there a way that i can make it run sequentially? like run domain1 script wait one minute then run domain2...looping through the url list.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in a bash script, like

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php -q /home/domain1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tdw/postit.php > /dev/null
sleep 60s
/usr/bin/php -q /home/domain2/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tdw/postit.php > /dev/null
sleep 60s
/usr/bin/php -q /home/domain3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tdw/postit.php > /dev/null
sleep 60s
# and so on...
```

and start that from cron.

If the pathes are all alike except the domain name, you could also use a php script, which generates the correct path for every domain and then executes the script via [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). For example, it could iterate over the contents of the /home folder via the [directory functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php) of PHP. That way, you do not have to update your script when you add a domain.

A script like that would look like

```
<?php

$template = '/usr/bin/php -q /home/%s/public_html/wp-content/plugins/tdw/postit.php > /dev/null';

if ($handle = opendir('/home')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        $command = sprintf($template, entry);
        exec($command);
        sleep(60);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got a similar issue on a script I'm executing on my NAS via cron, turned out that there was an error in my query, I did miss the quotes

```
WHERE myvarcharfield = 12345
```

istead

```
WHERE myvarcharfield = '12345'
```

not sure why it seemed that script executed correctly anyway and after that break the loop but it also did not return an error